# Leaflet Map Overlay Icon Blank

Tags: image, leaflet, overlay

The icon for the map overlay toggler does not load on leaflet.

I had the same issue with the map marker however found a solution creating a new variable with L.icon

I have not been able to apply the same solution. There are no faults on the console. The file paths are correct. I have compared leaflets.css file to mine.

Any Ideas and thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: What framework are you using? How is the Leaflet CSS being loaded?

Comment: Hi Ivan, thank you for replying. I am using bootstrap and loading the leaflet.css linked in my html and opening on live server.

Comment: And I assume you have local copies of the Leaflet JS and CSS files, right?

Comment: BTW please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: yes they are located in my C: in specific folders

Comment: I'm gonna ask you to read https://leafletjs.com/download.html#using-a-downloaded-version-of-leaflet , very carefully. And look for 404 errors in your browser's console.

Comment: Ok, I have the icon now and I deleted my variable to recreate the map marker which has now revealed the correct leaflet.css map marker image. I have deleted the 'path/to' links from my html head which have removed all faults from the console. I believe the fault was that my 'images file' was not directly in the same folder/directory as 'leaflet.css'. Following your link above was solid advise. Thank you.

Comment: However applying these links to the html file throws a few errors in the console and without them there are zero errors. <link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/to/leaflet.css" />
<script src="/path/to/leaflet.js"></script> as advised in the leaflet download notes.